# PHP parse soapClient response transfer to a table

Tags: php, soap

I'm just on the hose and dont get on.

I am not a professional programmer but have so far with much reading and over numerous attempts everything so far created what I have undertaken, only with this I have probably found my masterpiece.

I have a response of a SOAP query and would like to display the values in a table for each powerUnitidentifier. What is the best way to do this?

````
(
    [RawData] => stdClass Object
        (
            [from] => 2022-05-10T01:00:00+02:00
            [to] => 2022-05-10T01:20:00+02:00
            [dataRecords] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [record] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [powerUnitIdentifier] => abc123
                                    [time] => 2022-05-10T01:00:00+02:00
                                    [fields] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [field] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [identifier] => 100
                                                            [value] => 0
                                                        )

                                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [identifier] => 101
                                                            [value] => 3.27
                                                        )

                                                    [2] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [identifier] => 102
                                                            [value] => 70.00
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [powerUnitIdentifier] => zyx321
                                    [time] => 2022-05-10T01:00:00+02:00
                                    [fields] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [field] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [identifier] => 100
                                                            [value] => 0
                                                        )

                                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [identifier] => 101
                                                            [value] => 3.19
                                                        )

                                                    [2] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [identifier] => 102
                                                            [value] => 70.00
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [2] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [powerUnitIdentifier] => abc123
                                    [time] => 2022-05-10T01:10:00+02:00
                                    [fields] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [field] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [identifier] => 100
                                                            [value] => 0
                                                        )

                                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [identifier] => 101
                                                            [value] => 3.15
                                                        )

                                                    [2] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [identifier] => 102
                                                            [value] => 70.00
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [3] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [powerUnitIdentifier] => zyx321
                                    [time] => 2022-05-10T01:10:00+02:00
                                    [fields] => stdClass Object
                                        (
                                            [field] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [identifier] => 100
                                                            [value] => 0
                                                        )

                                                    [1] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [identifier] => 101
                                                            [value] => 3.09
                                                        )

                                                    [2] => stdClass Object
                                                        (
                                                            [identifier] => 102
                                                            [value] => 70.00
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)```
````

Comment: You show what you have tried, but not what results you get. What is the specific problem you are running into? [Edit] the question and tell us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You loop over the section of the data, starting the foreach loop at the right level of your data structure

```
foreach($theName->RawData->DataRecords->record as $obj) {
    echo $obj->powerUnitIdentifier;
}
```

Or if you ment to process the sub array of that

```
foreach($theName->RawData->DataRecords->record as $obj) {
    echo $obj->powerUnitIdentifier . '<br>';
    foreach( $obj->fields as $field) {
        echo $field->identifier . ',' . $field->value . '<br>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This puts me in the right direction.